# Breaking the functionality of a "submit" button

Tags: php, python, html

So, to elaborate on the title, let's say that I have a

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
```

button on an HTML webpage with functionality similar to that of entering a username and password and then submitting that form using the POST HTTP method. For example:

```
<html>
</script>
<div align="center">
<form method="POST" action="sup.py" name="testing">
<table width="30%" height="50">
 <tr>
    <td width="100%" height="30" align="right">
        Username:</td>
    <td width="100%" height="30">
        <input type="username" name="username" size="20">
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" height="30" align="right">
        Password:</td>
    <td width="100%" height="30">
        <input type="password" name="password" size="20">
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" height="30" align="center" colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="submit_info">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
      </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I'd like to figure out if there's a way to prevent the form from being submitted when you do press "Submit" if the webpage is already up on another non-local webserver, effectually making nothing happen when you press the button, breaking its functionality.

I'm not sure but is it possible to break an HTML script on a public website (that's run using python scripts, hence the action in the code) locally in this context?

Thanks in advance, everyone and please don't hesitate to ask me to explain myself if anything's a bit off!

Comment: Ok so this is a bit odd... Am I right in saying you don't want to submit it if there is another user already on the page in another location?

Comment: I think **javascript** can help you out in this, first check the condition using **Ajax** then submit the form accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention something! The source code for the webpage is similar to the one I posted above, but I'm not allowed to tamper with it (cuz it's on a separate webserver). Is there any way to locally break the page through a script (kinda like using inspect element)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change button type from submit to button

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

change your type of input like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="Submit">
```

button will take no action like href="#"